# Boost returning CPU time of 0

Tags: c++, boost, cpu-time

I'm trying to measure the CPU time for functions within my C++ program. I am doing this using the boost library. When I run my program however I get a result of 0 seconds. I'm new to boost so if someone could point me in the right direction?

How can I make this return a time that I can actually use, such as 0.00156 or something?

Code: Inside main()

```
boost::timer::cpu_timer timer;

std::cout << tree1.search("Cork") << std::endl;

//Print CPU TIME
boost::timer::cpu_times elapsed = timer.elapsed();
std::cout << " CPU TIME: " << (elapsed.user + elapsed.system) / 1e9 << " seconds" << std::endl;
```

Comment: What happens if you write `double(1e9)` instead of just `1e9`?

Comment: returns the same result

Comment: Have you tried printing out the raw values returned for `elapsed.user` and `elapsed.system`? What do you get?

Comment: That still returns 0.

Comment: Perhaps your timer resolution is really coarse and the job takes less than one tick.

Comment: What type is `tree1`? How many entries in it?

Comment: @n.m.: It might not have to be all that coarse, even.

Comment: Try `for( int i=0; i < SomeBigNumber; ++i ) { std::cout << tree1.search("Cork") << std::endl; }` and see if that makes any difference. I've found precision of `boost::timer::cpu_timer` to be quite low on my machine, unless the code to be tested runs for a few seconds at least.

Comment: @FredLarson tree1 is a BST with 50 nodes that contains a city object

Comment: So that shouldn't take more than 6 comparisons to find a match (assuming it's balanced). Probably not enough time to exceed a timer tick.

Comment: @zett42 it works, fudges the numbers a bit but I suppose if I do the same thing to all the functions I need to test it'll even out.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `boost` `chrono`;

```
boost::timer::cpu_timer timer;

std::cout << tree1.search("Cork") << std::endl;

//Print CPU TIME
boost::chrono::duration<double> elapsed = boost::chrono::nanoseconds(timer.elapsed().user);
std::cout << " CPU TIME: " << seconds.count() << "s\n" << " seconds" << std::endl;
```

Comment: That still makes no difference. Could it be that the function just doesn't take long enough to execute and the CPU time is so small that it can't be displayed?

Comment: While it's a good idea to use `chrono` instead of Boost. I doubt it has better time resolution. I wouldn't expect this to make any difference.